# Pylint works with some files, but not others

Tags: macos, python-3.x, pylint

I'm having some issues with pylint on OS X. Here's some background of my setup first though:

- Python2.x and Python3.x both installed via homebrew
- Pylint installed via `pip3 install pylint`

So when I run `pylint pythonfile.py` I get [this output](http://pastebin.com/4x5LDii6)

So I'm stuck and I have no idea where to go with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're using Python 3.5? The latest Pylint does not work with Python 3.5 yet, but a newer version with support for Python 3.5 will be released soon.